# How to call a method after changed DependencyProperty

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, custom-controls, dependency-properties

I have a `WPF` Application using `MVVM` pattern. I have a Window in my project and use a `CustomControl` in my Window.
I need two commands in my Window for Start and Stop in my `CustomControl` . So I use a `bool DependencyProperty` like this :

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty IsStartModeProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "IsStartMode", typeof(bool), typeof(RadarView), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false, OnCurrentReadingChanged));

public bool IsStartMode {
    get { return (bool)GetValue(IsStartModeProperty); }
    set { SetValue(IsStartModeProperty, value); }
}
```

Also following method is use for callback delegate in my dependency property:

```
public static void OnCurrentReadingChanged(DependencyObject doj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs dp) {
    if (IsStartMode)
        Start();
    else
        Stop();
}
```

My problem is in use from `IsStartMode` property in up method, because this is not static. It has a build error.

Is Correct my solution? if is correct what I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to cast the first method argument to your Dependency Object class:

```
public static void OnCurrentReadingChanged(DependencyObject doj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs dp) 
{ 
    var myObject = (RadarView)doj;

    if (myObject.IsStartMode) 
        myObject.Start(); 
    else 
        myObject.Stop(); 
}
```

(As a side note, I would call the property `IsRunning`.)